# Ist "Wie ist dein Name" gutes Deutsch?

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality

Vor allem in synchronisierten Filmen hört man den Ausdruck "Wie ist dein Name" sehr häufig. Für mich klingt das sehr seltsam, ich würde nie auf die Idee kommen, jemanden zu fragen, wie sein Name ist. Viel mehr würde ich fragen "Wie heisst du?" oder "Wie lautet dein Name?", wobei letzteres auch eher seltsam ist, sich jedoch "richtiger" anhört als "Wie ist dein Name".

Nun jetzt die Frage, ist "Wie ist dein Name" gutes Deutsch? Wird das in Deutschland gebraucht? Oder ist es eine schlechte Übersetzung von "What is your name"? Ich kann nur soviel sagen, dass der Ausdruck hier in der Schweiz unbekannt ist, eshalb er für mein Ohr wohl auch so seltsam klingt.

Comment: Auch in Deutschland würde man eher _"Wie heisst Du/heissen Sie"_ sagen.

Comment: Vielleicht macht man das so um die Lippensynchronisierung besser  stimmen zu lassen?

Comment: I don't think I say "Wie ist dein Name?" a lot, but I'm pretty sure I use this phrase occasionally. For instance, after asking the first person "Wie heißt du?", I might say to a second person: "Und wie ist dein Name?". In that case, it's obviously merely for avoing the very same phrase. But I definitely ask somebody "Wie war dein Name nochmal?" when I forgot somebody's name. (This example is actually also mentioned somewhere in this pretty long answer.)

Answer (score 8):

Ein Beamter oder Angestellter einer Behörde kann durchaus so fragen, natürlich in der Sie-Form:

> Wie ist Ihr Name?

Das wäre dann sinngemäß eine auf höflich gebürstete Aufforderung:

> Bitte nennen Sie Ihren Namen.

In der du-Form ist die Frage im Normalfall ungewöhnlich, aber situativ denkbar. Sie klingt 'amtlich', z.B. könnte ein Polizist, der an einer Schule ermittelt, die Kinder einer Klasse der Reihe nach fragen:

> und wie ist **dein** Name?

Noch höflicher als allein in Frageform wäre der Satz im Jargon eines Verkäufers oder Versicherungsvertreters:

> Darf ich um Ihren Namen bitten?

Direkter und fordernder wäre die Kurzversion (Polizist fragt mich nach 'Geblitzt-Werden')

> Ihr Name, bitte.

In solchen Fällen wäre es unüblich, die Frage mit 'heißen' zu stellen, es ist eine reine Datenabfrage zum Ausfüllen eines Formulars bzw. zum Füttern einer Datenbank, es sollen Angaben gemacht und nicht eine Beziehung aufgebaut werden. Überhaupt frage ich mich, ob es nicht etwas unhöflich, weil zu direkt und konfrontativ wäre, jemanden Unbekannten in der Sie-Form zu fragen:

> Wie heißen Sie?

Die Bitte um diese Information braucht unter Gleichgestellten irgendeine Höflichkeits-Verpackung, z.B.

> Darf ich um Ihren Namen bitten?

Früher war man da noch weitaus zimperlicher und kratzfüßiger:

> Wie ist / war Ihr werter Name?

oder gar

> Wie darf ich Sie ansprechen?

oder man versuchte es augenzwinkernd mit

> Würden Sie mir Ihren Namen verraten?

Etwas anders läuft die Situation, wenn man den Namen bereits weiß, aber die Person noch nicht erlebt hat. Typisches Beispiel 'Bewerbungsgespräch':

> Sie sind also die Frau / der Herr Knipperdolling.

Wenn man nur vermutet, den Namen zu kennen, kann man fragen

> Sind Sie nicht der Herr / die Frau Hackenbusch?

oder

> Sie sind doch (bestimmt) (der) Herr / (die) Frau Hackenbusch, richtig?

oder man sagt

> Sie müssen (der) Herr / (die) Frau Hackenbusch sein!

In ähnlichen Situationen - Tochter stellt der Familie jemanden vor - wird typischerweise ein vielsagendes 'ich hab schon viel von Ihnen gehört' oder 'von Ihnen hört man ja ganz dolle Geschichten!' angeschlossen.

Darüber hinaus gibt es die Variante einer rhetorischen Frage. Man sagt sie vor allem, wenn man die Person bereits namentlich kennt. Man drückt damit Verwunderung (à la *du hier!?*) oder eine mehr oder weniger gespielte, ironische Überraschtheit aus:

> Wen haben wir denn **da**?

Dies ist dann nicht als echte Frage, sondern selbstgesprächsartig zu verstehen als 'damit, dich hier zu treffen, hab ich nun wirklich nicht gerechnet.'

Beim Sprechen über Dritte, z.B. unter Kollegen in der Kantine, kann es recht hemdsärmlig zugehen, je nach Region:

> ist das nicht die Müller aus der Personalabteilung?
>   is dat nich dat Müller von ausm Büro?
>   sag mal, ist das da vorne nicht die Müllersche aus'm Personalbüro?

**Auch nach meiner Einschätzung ist es unüblich, in privaten Kontakten die Frage nach dem Namen anders als mit 'heißen' zu formulieren**, wenn man sie direkt einem Gegenüber stellt. Ein

> Wie lautet dein Name?

klingt in meinen Ohren sehr steif und angestrengt förmlich.

Wenn man über eine dritte Person spricht, kann man auf beide Weisen fragen:

> (und) wie heißt er? / wie heißt er denn? / weißt du auch, wie der Mann heißt?

oder

> wie ist denn sein Name? / kennst du auch seinen Namen?

Wenn ich mir zwei Burschen vorstelle, denen eine attraktive Frau ins Blickfeld gerät, könnte ich mir Sätze vorstellen wie

> Wie, du kennst sie? Was weißt du über sie, wie heißt sie, was macht sie?

Dann wird auch gefragt

> Wer ist das? Kennst du sie etwa?

Die Frage kann man in dieser Form auch direkt stellen, z.B. bei einer Reihenabfrage:

> (und) wer bist du? / und wer sind Sie?

In der dritten Person erscheint mir das jedenfalls mit 'er' als zu schwerfällig:

> ??Wer ist er? / Wer ist dieser Mann?

Das würde ich als Frage nach dem Hintergrund und der Herkunft einer Person verstehen.

Kleine Kinder - oder Erwachsene in unernster Absicht - fragt man auch

> Hast du auch einen Namen (kleiner Mann)?

Wenn einem ein Name nicht einfällt, fragt man:

> Wie war noch gleich Ihr Name?

In der Du-Form gäbe das

> Tschuldigung, aber wie heißt du noch mal - tut mir leid, aber ich hab mir deinen Namen nicht gemerkt...

Aber auch

> Wie war noch mal dein Name?

oder

> Sagst du mir bitte noch mal deinen Namen?

In der dritten Person entsprechend

> Wie hieß er noch gleich - jetzt fällt mir doch tatsächlich sein Name nicht ein!

oder

> wie war noch gleich sein Name?

Bei Nachfragen, wenn ein Name nicht richtig verstanden wurde, kann man ebenfalls fragen

> Wie war der Name (noch mal)? / Wie war noch mal Ihr Name?

Wie man sieht, muss man unterscheiden zwischen

- Du und Sie, allgemeiner: nach der Beziehung
- 'unverstellt' (ganz direkt) und 'höflich'
- erstmaliger oder wiederholter Frage
- beiläufiger oder fokussierter Frage,
  sowie nach
- der Situation
- dem Bezug der Frage: Name des 'Gesprächspartners' oder Name einer dritten Person
- der An- oder Abwesenheit des Dritten in der Gesprächssituation, und natürlich
- dem Interesse des Fragestellers an der Person

ganz zu schweigen von magischen Anteilen: Ach wie gut, dass niemand weiß ... Oder, wie heißt es so schön im Lohengrin: Nie sollst du mich befragen...

Comment: Und ist „Wie ist dein Name?“ jetzt gutes Deutsch oder nicht? ;-)

Comment: @Philipp: Kommt drauf an, was man unter 'gut' versteht. Es ist in formell-asymmetrischen Kommunikationssituationen in der 'Sie'-Form üblich (Bsp. Arbeitsagentur), in der 'du'-Form denkbar, aber kaum üblich, z.B.: Trainer fragt Namen von Kindern der neuen Jugendmannschaft ab, um sie in eine Liste einzutragen. Die Normalvariante mit 'du' ist _Wie heißt du?_ Das ist dann aber weder 'gut' noch 'schlecht', bzw. genauso 'gut' wie die Tatsache, dass in einer Wohnung Wände vorhanden sind: _Wie, es gibt hier Wände, wow! Das ist aber gut!_ ;)

Comment: @Philipp: Und noch einmal zu Deiner Ausgangsfrage: 'Wie lautet dein Name?' würde ich selbst nicht sagen, auch nicht in der 'Sie'-Form, für manch anderen wäre diese bemühte Ausdrucksweise jedoch 'gutes Deutsch' bzw. besser als ein schlichtes 'Wie heißt du?'.

Answer (score 5):

Man kann weder sagen, dass *Wie ist Dein/Ihr Name* falsch oder schlechtes Deutsch sei, noch dass es spezifisch für Deutschland wäre.

Folgende Zitate belegen eine gelegentliche Verwendung schon seit dem 17. Jahrhundert:

> - Fassen Sie sich und antworten Sie mir: Wie ist Ihr Name? <sup>[Die drey Zwillingsbrüder von Venedig. Wien 1778](https://books.google.de/books?id=ahdYAAAAcAAJ&dq=%22Wie%20ist%20Ihr%20Name%22&pg=PA95#v=onepage&q=%22Wie%20ist%20Ihr%20Name%22&f=false)</sup>
> - Nun wol mein Herr: lassen Sie uns bei dem Kürzesten anfangen ! Wie ist Ihr Name? <sup>[Lessing 1750: Der Schatz](https://books.google.de/books?id=7EY_AAAAcAAJ&dq=%22Wie%20ist%20Ihr%20Name%22&pg=PA122#v=onepage&q=%22Wie%20ist%20Ihr%20Name%22&f=false)</sup>
> - Wie ist Ihr Name? <sup>[Lehrerkarte Berlin, 1870](https://books.google.de/books?id=raFSAAAAcAAJ&dq=%22Wie%20ist%20Ihr%20Name%22&pg=PA27#v=onepage&q=%22Wie%20ist%20Ihr%20Name%22&f=false)</sup>

Ein [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=Wie%20ist%20Ihr%20Name&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWie%20ist%20Ihr%20Name%3B%2Cc0) zeigt auch, dass die Verwendung im schriftlichen Deutsch seit der Verbreitung synchronisierter Filme nicht zugenommen hat:

[image]

Dennoch würde auch ich spontan eher eine [andere Formulierung](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/43919/23) wählen.

<sub>**Anmerkung:** Zur Suche habe ich die Sie-Form gewählt, weil man annehmen muss, dass man den Namen einer Person mir der man per Du ist, eher kennt.</sub>

Comment: Interesting quotes from classical works of literature. Still, in everyday communication (and that's what the question was intended for, I believe) *Wie ist ihr Name* should be avoided. It is understandable, but awkward.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: ungewöhnlich finde ich auch, aber "schlechtes Deutsch" oder "schlechte Übersetzung" geht m.E. zu weit, wenn schon Lessing das benutzt hat; und es stammt dann definitiv **nicht** aus der Filmsynchronisation (darum geht es in der Frage).

Answer (score 1):

`Wie ist dein Name?` klingt sehr distanziert, ist aber nicht falsch. Es wird mehr bei amtlichen Handlungen verwendet. Otto Normalbürger fragt `Wie heißt du?`.

Comment: Gerade bei amtlichen Handlungen würde es dann aber "Wie ist ihr Name?" heißen.

Comment: @Iris: ja, genau, mit Höflichkeitsanrede "Ihr" dann auch anstatt "Dein". Erwischt ein Lehrer einen Schüler bei etwas, würde er aber durchaus "Wie ist dein Name?" fragen, um Respekt einzufordern.

Comment: Äh ja, natürlich mit großgeschriebenen "I". "Wie ist Ihr Name?"

Comment: @äöü: ... oder um einzuschüchtern, strenger, schneidender zu klingen, um ein bisschen Angst bzw. um deutlich zu machen, dass es nicht nur um ein bisschen verschüttete Milch geht.

Answer (score 1):

Die Frage mit *"Wie"* einzuleiten könnte (nach Schul- bzw. Lehrbuch) auch nach einem **Adjektiv** fragen. Insofern darf man sich nicht besonders wundern, wenn man als Antwort *"voll von Konsonanten"*, *"grün"* (mag keinen Sinn machen) oder Dergleichen erhält.

Comment: Mein Name ist viersilbig, Utz Viersilbig.